# Export and Import View STRUCTURE in MongoDB

Tags: database, mongodb, view

I created a view in MongoDB. This view basically ties up together two collections, one of people and another with countries, as there is one field in the PERSON collection which relates to the country in the COUNTRY collection.

I don't recall exactly how I structured the view, otherwise I would just recreate it from scratch, but I need to copy that view to another server, and I haven't found a way through MongoDB Compass or the mongo shell to generate a "mysqldump" of that view, so I can execute it in the destination server for recreating it.

I was hoping this to be very straightforward, but I haven't found answers regarding this in google. Either I am asking the wrong questions, or I am looking for something that doesn't exist because it doesn't make sense.

I have tried exporting in MongoDB Compass, but in reality that exports the data, which is a merge of the two collections (Person + Country) and not the structure, which is what I need.

Any hints?